# Understanding and control of sqlite version loaded

Tags: bash, sqlite, batch-file

Interactively I more or less know what *sqlite3* I'm getting but in a bash batch script it seems I have no hope!

**Interactive bash session**

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin

$ alias -p |grep sql
alias sqlite3='/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.44.2/bin/sqlite3'

$ which sqlite3
/usr/bin/sqlite3

$ `which sqlite3` -version
3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19 2ef4f3a5b1d1d0c4338f8243d40a2452cc1f7fe4

$ sqlite3 -version
3.44.2 2023-11-24 11:41:44 ebead0e7230cd33bcec9f95d2183069565b9e709bf745c9b5db65cc0cbf92c0f (64-bit)
```

*which* shows builtin  /usr/bin/sqlite3

*which* is designed to search just the path and ignores functions and alias effects?

Plain invocation gets the much later brew installed version, as wanted.

## In batch files

I have the same PATH and alias in bash shell runs but always get the built in 3.8 version unless I do some specific call to /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.44.2/bin/sqlite3

In particular the PATH and alias do not seem to help, neither did a function if I defined at the start of the batch file.

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash
export alias sqlite3='/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.44.2/bin/sqlite3'
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.44.2/bin/sqlite3 -version
printenv
echo =====================
echo
export -p
echo =====================
echo

sqlite3 -version
exit /b 0
```

Produces

```
3.44.2 2023-11-24 11:41:44 ebead0e7230cd33bcec9f95d2183069565b9e709bf745c9b5db65cc0cbf92c0f (64-bit)
<snip>
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin

<snip>
declare -x sqlite3="/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.44.2/bin/sqlite3"
=====================

3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19 2ef4f3a5b1d1d0c4338f8243d40a2452cc1f7fe4
./test: line 12: exit: /b: numeric argument required
```

What am I missing about use in batch scripts, please?? I don't want to resort to links etc, just tell this batch file to use the new version, somehow without giving a specific path everywhere!

(Mat is correct this is more a shell environment & bash issue. I started off believing an unwanted behaviour was linked to the -batch switch given to sqlite3 but proved this was not so and deleted that posting. It was purely the version getting invoked.)

OK. Found it I think... there is no link in the brew installation to the binary. Reason maybe that this is an old macOS 10.11.6 El Capitan that brew warns is no longer supported and there may be problems. As I needed a later sqlite to fix a problem I expect I had to be creative/persistent some years ago with getting it there and never noticed/knew the link was missing but just added an alias.

Comment: You have an executable in a `PATH` directoty **and** another executable linked to by an alias. They are different. This is nothing special to sqlite, you just have more than one version of the same program. And executing them of course yields different results.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368246/cant-use-alias-in-script-even-if-i-define-it-just-above

Comment: I have tidied up my question in light of clarifications. Still confused why batch file does not behave the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think you have gone doubly wrong if you:

- use aliases for this sort of thing, and
- use **homebrew** but then use version-specific things like `/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.44.2/bin/sqlite3`

Why? When you use aliases, they won't work in `crontab` or subprocess calls in Python for example, or in `systemd` scripts.

As you are using **homebrew**, its installation suggests you add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH, or `/opt/homebrew/bin` on Apple silicon. **homebrew** itself creates symbolic links from these directories to the specific versions. That means you always use `/usr/local/bin` everywhere in your scripts and then you just do `brew upgrade` and all your scripts use the latest version of all the tools without needing change and **homebrew** can link/unlink whatever version you want.

So, in short, my recommendation would be to simply ensure your PATH is correct and specifies the order of your preferences, avoid aliases and version-specific things and then everything will work as you want.

---

If you want to see the version-specific links **homebrew** creates, run:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Helpful, thanks Mark. However this is Intel Mac and first in PATH is indeed /usr/local/bin, same in my interactive and in the batch file (I echo'd it out to check) so I expect the same sqlite to get invoked by the same command - but NO, not what we saw. If I delete the alias in interactive shell that also then gets the old version... BUT looking at links in /usr/local/bin is instructive... amending my answer and awarding you for the pointer...